# Trying to add a variable (IP address) with seq to print a list of variables(IP) in order

Tags: linux, shell

Ok, I am trying to use a variable (IP address) and use SEQ to add to the variable. Ex 198.186.1 and list 198.186.1, 198.186.2, etc

```
VALUE=$1
echo SCAN $VALUE.0/24
for i in $(seq 1 1 5);
do
    echo $($VALUE+$i)
done
```

I get it to print the 'VALUE' but its always +1
(198.186.1+1)

Comment: Arithmetic is `$((expression))`, not `$(expression)`

Comment: You should know that, since you wrote `$(seq 1 1 5)` to execute a command -- that's obviously not an arithmetic expression.

Comment: This doesn't print `$VALUE+$i`, it attempts to execute that string as a command. Unless you have a script named `192.168.1+1` that's going to give you a `command not found` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate an arithmetic expression, you use `$(($VALUE+$i))`, with two parentheses. `$(...)` is command substitution, it expects the contents to be a command (like `seq 1 1 5`), and it's replaced with the output of the command.

But you shouldn't be using arithmetic here, because `$VALUE` isn't a number. You should just concatenate the variables.

```
echo $VALUE.$i
```